# Cannot run Hello World on Google App Engine Windows

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have [downaloded and installed Python 2.7.6](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/) in my Windows and I have also installed the latest version of the [GAE SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) for Windows as well.

I have the following configurations on my GAE:
[image: GAE_configs]

I am running an Hello World project with the following files:

Main.py

```
import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: HelloWorld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

However, When I click the button **Run**, in order to runt he project, I get the following errors in the LOG output:

```
2013-12-04 14:51:49 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=8080', '--admin_port=8000', 'D:\\Users\\pedro\\Desktop\\HelloWorld']"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 197, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 193, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 872, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 865, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 657, in start
    options.yaml_files)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 549, in __init__
    module_configuration = ModuleConfiguration(yaml_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 82, in __init__
    self._yaml_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 266, in _parse_configuration
    return appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo_includes.py", line 63, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\appinfo.py", line 1756, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 226, in Parse
    self._HandleEvents(self._GenerateEventParameters(stream, loader_class))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: Unable to assign value 'HelloWorld' to attribute 'application':
Value 'HelloWorld' for application does not match expression '^(?:(?:[a-z\d\-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!\-)[a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$'
  in "D:\Users\pedro\Desktop\HelloWorld\app.yaml", line 1, column 14
2013-12-04 14:51:50 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Thus I have the following questoins:

1. I have created this project by going to File -> New application, but apparently my auto-generated app.yaml file is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?
2. I have tried to use Python 3.3 first, but it was not working. GAE only works with Python 2.7 right? I am doing everythign correctly right?
3. When I click the Browse button I get the error saying that no browser is specified. How do I fix that?

Thanks for any help if possible :S

Comment: Your application ID(HelloWorld) is invalid

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the regex that isn't matching, the app name needs to be lowercase:

```
>>> regex = r'^(?:(?:[a-z\d\-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!\-)[a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$'
>>> print(re.match(regex, 'HelloWorld'))
None
>>> print(re.match(regex, 'helloworld'))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x13ac308>
```

Comment: WHat!? I had no idea about that! Thanks!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the same errors. The weird thing is that my app ID is "behnam-features-testing" and when I change it to "behnam-feature-testing" (removing the s from features), then it works. I can't use "behnam-feature-testing" since my app ID in the Google Developers Console is "behnam-features-testing". Any idea? the launcher doesn't deploy the app either, it says it does but when I go to my-app-id.appspot.com/filename.php it says "Error: NOT_FOUND". I should also mention that it used to work, but not anymore.

Comment: @aquavitae Thanks man, this works! Can anyone explain why Google App Engine doesn't allow uppercase app names?...

Comment: Thanks man I had the same issue. changed the app name all in lowercase and now it is working fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Your application identifier('HelloWorld') is invalid. You should use the one you created in the Administration Console according to the [GAE doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_About_app_yaml).

The ID will be the subdomain of your GAE application when it deployed in appspot.com. That's why the app id should match the regex `r'^(?:(?:[a-z\d\-]{1,100}\~)?(?:(?!\-)[a-z\d\-\.]{1,100}:)?(?!-)[a-z\d\-]{0,99}[a-z\d])$'`.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with the same errors. The weird thing is that my app ID is "behnam-features-testing" and when I change it to "behnam-feature-testing" (removing the s from features), then it works. I can't use "behnam-feature-testing" since my app ID in the Google Developers Console is "behnam-features-testing". Any idea? the launcher doesn't deploy the app either, it says it does but when I go to my-app-id.appspot.com/filename.php it says "Error: NOT_FOUND". I should also mention that it used to work, but not anymore.